# Testing identity of two data-blocks

Tags: python, scripting, data-blocks

What is the proper way to test the identity of two objects?

Usually I do this:

```
if ob1 == ob2:
```

Or if the references have become outdated, it may be safer to hold onto names and see if they still exist:

```
objects = bpy.data.objects
ob_a = objects.get(name_a)
if ob_a is not None:
    ob_b = objects.get(name_b)
    if ob_a == ob_b:
        # found a match!
```

In Python, you're taught that **equality** is not the same as **identity**. Theoretically, there can be two indistinguishable Blender objects. So what I'd really like to do is test *identity*:

```
if ob1 is ob2:
```

However, in the Blender console:

```
C.object is C.object
```

returns `False`! Why is this so, and what is the recommended way for determining the identity of two objects?

Comment: What do you mean by "the pointers have become outdated"? Python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: Well, it actually kind of does, but I changed the wording to "references", since that's usually what they are called in Python instead of "pointers".

Comment: There is a distinction between the two, of course, but from a high-level they work the same way. In Blender, the reference to an object can become invalid. For example, if you delete the object, while holding on to a reference to it.

Comment: If the reference is out-dated its **not** safer to do ``if ob1.name == ob2.name``, since this is reading from the reference (rather then just comparing it).

Comment: @CharlesL Python doesn't have native Pointers (unless you count `ctypes`), but internally (in the Py-C-API), pointers are used, ideally script authors wouldn't have to care about this but there are exceptions to that.

Comment: @ideasman42 Right! Actually in practice I do it more safely. Updated that so that nobody copies it.

Comment: Updated to reduce 4 lookups into 2 (lookups can be slow with 10000+ objects)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, for the `bpy` api use `==`, instead of `is` or comparing the name (which is error prone).

Blender data-blocks ***** happen not to be Python objects, that is to say, when Blender creates a mesh for example, there exists no Python object for it, until a script asks for one, The way the Python API works, each data-block is a reference to Blender data. therefor `id(bpy.context.object) == id(bpy.context.object)` won't be equal since each time a new python-object is created.

## Note:

This is not the case for **all** areas of Blender, The game-engine (`bge`) and the `bmesh` api's can use identity for comparisons.

## Note:

If you do want a unique `id()` for a data-block you can do:
`ob1.as_pointer() == ob2.as_pointer()`, this is specific to the `bpy` api.

* *In Blender data-block is a general term for a scene, group, mesh, image, material, texture... etc, (avoiding the term **object** since its confusing in this context)*

Comment: I see in the API that `as_pointer()` returns an integer. So this can be used to compare datablocks even after they are deleted? (Not saying that would be a good idea...)

Comment: Furthermore, it looks like you could then be more Pythonic and write: `ob1.as_pointer() is ob2.as_pointer()`, recovering the `is` syntax.

Comment: And is it possible that a datablock will maintain its content, but have its memory location shifted? (In other words can the value returned by `as_pointer()` become stale, despite the datablock still existing?)

Comment: Strictly speaking you shouldn't use `as_pointer()` on a data-block that's been freed, Since its possible a newly allocated object has the same address, In general its best do avoid holding references to objects for extended periods where you aren't sure if they are removed or not on future access.

Comment: Also note that if an object is deleted and then 'UNDO'ne, `as_pointer()` method will return a different address than the one prior to deleting.

Answer (score 6):

In (C)Python, the `is` operator is based on `id()`, which returns the memory address of a python object. For some reason, calling `id(bpy.context.active_object)` consecutively does not return the same value. I assume this is an implementation detail(or bug) of the Blender Python API.

Without `id()` working as expected, you can't use `is` for comparison. But `==` works just fine from my quick testing.

You are right that using obj.name to compare object is not ideal. Use `BlenderObject == BlenderObject` when possible.