# how can i compare whether an armature is the parent of an object?

Tags: python

i tried:

```
>>> armature
bpy.data.armatures['Armature']

>>> C.object.parent
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> id(armature)
5263333632

>>> id(C.object.parent)
5263335552

>>> C.object.parent.as_pointer()
5630907912

>>> armature.as_pointer()
5304812232
```

as you can see, they are different, although it is the same armature.

I don't wanna compare by name because this is not safe according to another answer here on BSE.

Comment: I think this is intended. See https://developer.blender.org/T88914

Comment: thanks! so should i compare via name then? or what is the way to go?

Comment: I think comparing by name is the most reliable here, if you don't change them somewhere in your code beforehand. Could you add the link to the answer where it says you shouldn't do it so I can explore why ?

Comment: Also be careful, `bpy.types.Armature` is accessed via `obj.data` so you should test `C.object.parent.data.as_pointer()` and `armature.as_pointer()` instead. The same way you can't compare `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]` and `bpy.data.meshes["Cube"]`

Comment: link here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5950/testing-identity-of-two-data-blocks